# IE9 rendering issue

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I've been trying to figure this issue out for about an hour now. I've asked some friends but they didn't have much luck either.

The problem is with this site: http://tomdwyerdesign.com/
Load it in Chrome and it's fine. Load it in IE10 and it's fine... load it in IE9 and it's not.

It loses a good portion of its css. I've used the html5shiv trick and still it refuses to work.

Another website: http://tomdwyerdesign.com/new 
this loads fine and shares almost an identical header.

Anyone know why IE9 won't render this correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE is going into quirks mode on your new site. Checking with [W3 Validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://tomdwyerdesign.com/&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) shows a warning that is likely your problem: IE will go into quirks mode if you have comments before your doctype.

Try moving your doctype before the comments, and see if that helps.

Comment: It's not _quite_ as weird as it sounds. IE will go into quirks mode whenever the doctype is not the first tag in the document, not just when preceeded by a comment.

Comment: It is weird because IE is the only browser that does that.

Comment: Actually, good point. Looking at the grammars for XML/SGML, it should be valid to put a comment before the doctype.

Comment: @TomDwyer If this solved your issue, you should accept the answer :)